# Zero-initialized, unnamed, temporary unsigned int

Tags: c++, gcc, initialization, clang, language-lawyer

Am I right to interpret `unsigned int{};` as [zero-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) of a temporary `unsigned int` without a name in the contexts provided below? The example does not work with clang or gcc, but compiles fine in Visual Studio: https://godbolt.org/z/LYWCCN

```
int ifun(int value) {
    return value * 10;
}

unsigned int uifun(unsigned int value) {
    return value * 10u;
}

int main() {
    // does not work in gcc and clang
    unsigned int{};
    unsigned int ui = uifun(unsigned int{});

    // works with all three compilers, also unsigned{}; works
    int{};
    int i = ifun(int{});
}
```

Comment: I understand that this is a theoretical question; but still, it appears to me that all use cases (for example, using this as an initialization or function argument or as the right hand side in an assignment, possibly in order to have the desired overload resolution) are solved by a static cast or even implicit conversions, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang and Gcc are right. `unsigned int{};` is considered as [explicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) firstly, which only works with single-word type name; while `unsigned int` (and `int*` etc) is not but `int` is.

(emphasis mine)

> 5) A **single-word type name** followed by a *braced-init-list* is a prvalue of the specified type `designating a temporary (until C++17)` `whose result object is (since C++17)` [direct-list-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) with the specified *braced-init-list*.

As the workaround, you can

```
using unsigned_int = unsigned int;
unsigned_int{};
```

As the result it'll value-initialize (zero-initialize) a temporary `unsigned int` as you expected.

Comment: Are you sure about `(unsigned int){}`? [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/AHs7Z2)

Comment: `(unsigned int){}` is invalid because `{}` is not an expression.

Comment: And what is `(unsigned int){5}`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a type alias to get around the limitation.

```
using UI = unsigned int;
UI{};
UI ui = uifun(UI{});
```